# How can I explain Pigeon Hole Principle to a child in a simple manner?

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

There is a exhibition in our school.I took up mathematics part in the exhibition.
all types of people will be there.

can anyone suggest me how can i explain PHP to small children ??

how can i make it interesting to them??

Comment: Do you have access to pigeons?

Comment: i am not joking

Comment: The pigeonhole principle is also called Dirichlet's box principle, which suggests a fairly obvious way of illustrating it.

Comment: @carmichael561, well, the name "pigeonhole principle" is as suggestive as that, really! No need to go looking for another name ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you didn't fold your laundry last time  so all of your socks are mixed up in your drawer. Now you only want to leave the house if you are wearing matching socks. If you have $7$ pairs of socks then clearly if you remove $8$ socks from the drawer youll have at least $1$ matching pair.

Answer (score 1):

$n$ siblings/friends/etc go trick-or-treating on Halloween. At one door, they are given $n+1$ candies. One of them will necessarily end up with $2+$ candies. Most small kids can likely relate to that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Have them try to put $n+1$ (wrapped) candies in $n$ boxes.